# Was there any US political campaign that included Gini index improvement?

Tags: united-states, campaigning, inequality, indicators

This [CIA online article](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/2172rank.html) tells us a little about the Gini index:

> Distribution of family income - Gini index measures the degree of
>   inequality in the distribution of family income in a country. The more
>   nearly equal a country's income distribution, the lower its Gini
>   index,

The table indicates a fairly modest place for United States (41), but the data is old (2007).

I am wondering if any US political program has included improvement of this index or it is too vague/abstract to include such a thing within a campaign.

**Question:** Was there any US political campaign that included Gini index improvement?

Comment: By "improvement" I assume you mean "reduction". I also suppose that vague references to "reducing inequality" are not the answer that you are looking for.

Comment: @JamesK - yes, "reducing inequality" is the actually meaning of Gini improvement/reduction, but I am curios if any party or politicians actually used this index explicitly.

Comment: Through what mechanism would you expect a political campaign to change the Gini index?

Comment: @DanHall - I do not expect that. Instead a political campaign might promise inequality reduction and include a reference to Gini index.

Comment: Can anybody recommend some good learning material on the Gini index? I'm interested in knowing, in particular, what conditions are required for it to be indicative of things like life quality, society stability, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandria_Ocasio-Cortez), a Democrat candidate for Congress from New York has [mentioned it recently](https://www.cnsnews.com/news/article/susan-jones/aiming-us-house-seat-ocasio-cortez-tweets-about-gini-coefficient).

> Wondering: How many other House Democrats have a degree in Economics like I do? Trying to find who out here is going to be in the Gini Coefficient Appreciation Squad.

Comment: I thought she was a self-identified socialist?  Or is she both?

Comment: @KDog she won a Democratic primary, so I think it's reasonable to call her a Democrat. Similarly wikipedia says she is a member of Democratic Socialists of America and specifically wants guaranteed jobs and single payer health care so I think calling her a socialist isn't unfair.